# PostgreSQL advisory lock stays after user disconnect

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a backend application that implements session level advisory lock. However, if the client suddenly loses the connection (e.g forcing reboot while connected) the advisory lock stays there and will not disappear.

Is there a way to always make the lock expire after a dropped connection?

Thanks.

Comment: `While a flag stored in a table could be used for the same purpose, advisory locks are faster, avoid table bloat, and are automatically cleaned up by the server at the end of the session.` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html So as long as you have timeout on connections then you are fine.

Answer (score 7):

I assume that the lock stays around because the backend process is still there.

Unless the server tries to contact the client, it can take a long time for the operating system to detect that the client socket is no longer there, which is when the PostgreSQL backend will be terminated.

You can set the PostgreSQL parameter [`tcp_keepalives_idle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-TCP-KEEPALIVES-IDLE) to a small value to reduce the time until a dead connection is detected.